# How add event listener to image in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to attach some mouse event on a images in my canvas.

I've tried this, but it's still doestn't work.

```
    var pointer = new Image();
    pointer.src = "/img/line_point.png";
    pointer.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(pointer, 55,123);
    }
    pointer.addEventListener("mouseover", maap, false);
```

Comment: Use canvas library like [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/).

Comment: What does the code look like with the below answer? I am having the same issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add the event listener to the canvas element and then manually check if the events x and y parameters are over the image drawn on your canvas.

Comment: Is it possible to find more flexibility solutions?

Comment: Well the event listeners are bound to elements. The only element you have is the canvas element.

Answer (score 2):

a `canvas` doesn't have a structure to remember objects drawn into it. Its just a `flat` canvas having pixels in it. If you need to to use objects in it switch to [`SVG`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). There are many `SVG` libraries in Javascript. such as [`d3`](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) [`Raphael`](http://raphaeljs.com/)

with a plain svg you can do it like

```
<svg width="4in" height="3in" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image id="myImg" x="200" y="200" width="100px" height="100px"></image>
</svg>
```

You can even use `document.getElementById('myImg')` or `jQuery('#myImg')` to add Events to It.

If you want to stick with Canvas add an event listener to the canvas itself and check the coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Reviving old thread with relevant sample from recent excellent book, "Core HTML5 Canvas", by David Geary.  This works fine in my application.

```
mycanvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
    var loc = windowToCanvas(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    $('#outputXY').val(loc.x + ',' + loc.y);
};

mycanvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var loc = windowToCanvas(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    $('#outputXY').val(loc.x + ',' + loc.y);
};

function windowToCanvas(x, y) {
    var r = mycanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { x: x - r.left * (mycanvas.width  / r.width),
             y: y - r.top  * (mycanvas.height / r.height)};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use SVG instead if you want attach event like this.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the canvas as a whiteboard in the classroom. Whatever teacher writes or draws on the whiteboard is the part of the board and you cannot pick any of them. If you want something that you can pick from the board you can use softboard at which you can put the objects and then move them from one position to another. SVG is an example of softboard, here each drawing (like line, arc) are objects and you can add click listeners on them.

If you want the canvas to behave like a SVG you will have to handle it. You can add click listener on the canvas and whenever an event is recieved on it, you need to calculate on which element this event has occurred.